# Java changing variable name changes program behaviour

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm

I found a scenario where java program behaves differently after renaming a variable. I understand this isn't actually code that anyone would use but if someone knows whats going on it would be nice to have an explanation. I tried this with java 1.6 on Eclipse Kepler.

```
package _test;

public class TestClass{
    public static void main(String...args){
        Object testClazz$1 = new Object (){
            public String toString() {
                return "hello";
            }
        };
        TestClass$1 test = new TestClass$1();
        System.out.println(testClazz$1.toString());
        test.doStuff();
    }
}

class TestClass$1{
    public void doStuff(){
        System.out.println("hello2");
    }
}
```

This outputs:

> hello
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   _test.TestClass$1.doStuff()V at _test.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:13)

As far as I understand the compiler creates a TestClass$1.class file for the testClazz$1 object and this causes a naming collision.

But after renaming the object to testClass$1:

```
package _test;

public class TestClass{
    public static void main(String...args){
        Object testClass$1 = new Object (){
            public String toString() {
                return "hello";
            }
        };

        TestClass$1 test = new TestClass$1();
        System.out.println(testClass$1.toString());
        test.doStuff();
    }
}

class TestClass$1{
    public void doStuff(){
        System.out.println("hello2");
    }
}
```

The output is:

> _test.TestClass$1@2e6e1408
>
> hello2

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: Not sure exactly why this is occurring but something to note about naming: It is bad practice to name your variables with a $ sign as this is typically reserved for a system generated variable. I'd be willing to bet this odd behavior is occurring because you are tripping over some system generated TestClass.

Comment: The system creates an anonymous class TestClass$1, it is still strange that this is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the classloader encounters the anonymous `Object() {...}` class it loads it under the name `TestClass$1`. This creates a conflict with `class TestClass$1 {...}` which was explicitly defined.

However, class name conflicts are handled rather ungracefully. [This bit of documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#resolveClass%28java.lang.Class%29) tells us that

> If the class c has already been linked, then this method simply returns.

That's what happens in your case. You only ever load one of the two `TestClass$1` classes.

The "different variable names" are *not* responsible for anything other than re-compiling and re-linking within your compiler. At this point, the classloader is free to pick whichever one of the two `TestClass$1` likes better and use that everywhere.

---

If you're using something like eclipse (like I am) then your bytecode will get cached, until a new `touch` operation on the source file (and updating of timestamps...). Here's what I did to reproduce (running openjdk 1.7, Eclipse Kepler under RedHat):

Put this inside a source file `TestClass.java`:

```
package javaclasses.classes;

public class TestClass{
    public static void main(String...args){
        Object o = new Object (){
            public String toString() {
                return "hello";
            }
        };

        TestClass$1 test = new TestClass$1();
        System.out.println(o.toString());
        test.doStuff();
    }
}

class TestClass$1{
    public void doStuff(){
        System.out.println("hello2");
    }
}
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> outputs:

```
javaclasses.classes.TestClass$1@42293b53
hello2
```

Open this in a console and `touch TestClass.java`

Go back in eclipse and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> now outputs:

```
hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javaclasses.classes.TestClass$1.doStuff()V
    at javaclasses.classes.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:13)
```

---

Conlusion: All that can be said definitively is that the default ClassLoader is unreliable for manually resolving classes with the same fully qualified names. Changing variable names doesn't matter, the updated timestamp on your source file does.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous classes are named automatically by appending a `$` sign and an increasing number to the name of the enclosing class.

In your first example the anoymous class will be named `TestClass$1` which has no `doStuff()` method, you only override `toString()` that's why you get `NoSuchMethodError` error.

In your 2nd example you already have a local variable named `TestClass$1`, so the auto-generated name chosen by the compiler will be a different name, most likely `TestClass$2`. Since you instantiate `TestClass$1` which is not an anonymous class but a class explicitly defined by you, that will be instantiated which has a `doStuff()` method which properly prints `"hello2"` and which does not override `Object.toString()` so printing the value returned by its `toString()` method will print the default value as specified in `java.lang.Ojbect` (which is the class name appended with a `@` sign followed by the default hash code in hexadecimal format).

**Conclusion:** While this is an interesting example, you should never use the `$` sign in your class names and in identifier names.

Comment: "The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems." quote from the [Java SE 7 language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to remove the "$" from the class names and renamed testClass$1 to t and changed the println slightly as follows:

```
public class TestClass{

    public static void main(String...args){
        Object t = new Object (){
            public String toString() {
                return "t.toString()";
            }
        };
        TestClass1 tc1 = new TestClass1();
        System.out.println(t.toString());
        tc1.doStuff();
    }
}

class TestClass1{
    public void doStuff(){
        System.out.println("TestClass1.doStuff()");
    }
}
```

Output is now:

```
t.toString()
TestClass1.doStuff()
```

Is this what you expect?

Comment: I was just interested in how jvm handles naming collisions, there is no sane reason for using $ sign in class and variable names.